# How to compute the Pearson’s correlation between variables using map() function?

Tags: r, dictionary

I'm having trouble using one of the `map()` functions in r to compute the correlation between variables in a data frame.
The question is "use one of the map functions to compute the Pearson’s correlation between Hepatitis A and each of the other 6 diseases, and return a double vector as the output."

[image]

The data shows each disease' yearly incidence rate each year.
I'm able to compute the correlation between Hepatitis A and other diseases by using the `cor()` function, but is there a way to use one of the `map()` functions to compute the correlation?

```
cor(US_incidence$`Hepatitis A`, US_incidence$Measles, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
cor(US_incidence$`Hepatitis A`, US_incidence$Mumps, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
cor(US_incidence$`Hepatitis A`, US_incidence$Pertussis, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
cor(US_incidence$`Hepatitis A`, US_incidence$Polio, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
cor(US_incidence$`Hepatitis A`, US_incidence$Rubella, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
cor(US_incidence$`Hepatitis A`, US_incidence$Smallpox, method = "pearson", use = "na.or.complete")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` directly across a subset of the data frame, because data frames are lists of vectors, and map can iterate over lists:

```r
map(your_data_frame[,-c(1,2)], #every column except year and Hep A
~ cor(US_incidence$`Hepatitis A`, ., method = "Pearson", use  = "complete.obs")
```

Note that if you wanted to vary your 'use' argument, as you do above, you need to create a list of character strings for that purpose and use `map2`.

You might also consider using `dplyr::summarise()` with `dplyr::across()`

```r
require(dplyr)

your_data_frame %>%
select(-year) %>% #don't need year column
ungroup() %>% # make sure d.f isn't grouped
summarise(across(everything(), function(x){
cor(`Hepatitis A`, x, method = "Pearson", use  = "complete.obs")
})) -> correlations
```

The above will give you a `Hepatitis A` column which shows correlation with itself, but you can just drop that if you want.

Comment: Thanks so much! That first code was what I was looking for! I also have another question. For each of the 7 diseases, how do I use loops or map functions to find the most positively (pearson's) correlated disease (except itself) and corresponding correlation?

Comment: Use `cor.test` rather than `cor` - instead of a length-one double, it returns a list. The p value is `result$p.value` and the value is `result$estimate`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector of column names that you want to apply the `cor` function to and then use `map_dbl` to get a double vector.

```
cols <- c('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Pertussis', 'Polio', 'Rubella', 'Smallpox')

result <- purrr::map_dbl(cols, 
                ~cor(US_incidence$`Hepatitis A`, US_incidence[[.x]], 
                   method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs"))
```